# postgresql jdbc very simple query and 56 rows, slow than 2x, 3x query with psql

Tags: jdbc, greenplum

I'm have an interesting issue with the PostgreSQL driver. In GreenPlum 5.26.0, I have a very simple SELECT query which `select sum(col) from table`. The table only has 56 rows. When I run this query with psql, it returns in 50ms. When I run it through my Java code, it take 2s-5s.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("startTime: " + start);
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db?loggerLevel=TRACE", "user", "password");
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select sum(num) as num from schema.table;");
         ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();) {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int res = resultSet.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("res: " + res);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}
```

I tried PostgreSQL JDBC 9.4-1205-jdbc41 and 42.2.16. The two versions both have the same problem, but with GreenPlum 6.8, I have no problem.

I have run arthas on my code during this exception, the PostgreSQL driver method
`org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream#readMore` is taking essentially all of the time.

It's been driving me crazy for days and would appreciate any insight.

udpate 2021-01-21:

table has only 56 rows. and i run \timing at local

```sh
dcw=# \timing
Timing is on.
dcw=# begin;select sum(num) as num from datagovernance.app_system_datagovernment_norm_1d;commit;
BEGIN
Time: 58.001 ms
  num   
--------
 323866
(1 row)

Time: 27.760 ms
COMMIT
Time: 3554.685 ms
```

And i run pg_test_fsync

```sh
5 seconds per test
O_DIRECT supported on this platform for open_datasync and open_sync.

Compare file sync methods using one 8kB write:
(in wal_sync_method preference order, except fdatasync
is Linux's default)
        open_datasync                   35915.892 ops/sec      28 usecs/op
        fdatasync                       29260.122 ops/sec      34 usecs/op
        fsync                           29845.096 ops/sec      34 usecs/op
        fsync_writethrough                            n/a
        open_sync                       33848.051 ops/sec      30 usecs/op

Compare file sync methods using two 8kB writes:
(in wal_sync_method preference order, except fdatasync
is Linux's default)
        open_datasync                   18039.438 ops/sec      55 usecs/op
        fdatasync                       29315.960 ops/sec      34 usecs/op
        fsync                           27148.788 ops/sec      37 usecs/op
        fsync_writethrough                            n/a
        open_sync                       16646.840 ops/sec      60 usecs/op

Compare open_sync with different write sizes:
(This is designed to compare the cost of writing 16kB
in different write open_sync sizes.)
         1 * 16kB open_sync write       31331.712 ops/sec      32 usecs/op
         2 *  8kB open_sync writes      16620.264 ops/sec      60 usecs/op
         4 *  4kB open_sync writes       8676.007 ops/sec     115 usecs/op
         8 *  2kB open_sync writes       4315.704 ops/sec     232 usecs/op
        16 *  1kB open_sync writes       2175.741 ops/sec     460 usecs/op

Test if fsync on non-write file descriptor is honored:
(If the times are similar, fsync() can sync data written
on a different descriptor.)
        write, fsync, close             27392.879 ops/sec      37 usecs/op
        write, close, fsync             27528.213 ops/sec      36 usecs/op

Non-Sync'ed 8kB writes:
        write                           469187.062 ops/sec       2 usecs/op
```

Now, the question is why commit take so long time?

Comment: Is the backend Greenplum or Postgres? Performance questions are highly product specific, and those two are sufficiently different that both tags don't make sense

Comment: the backend is Greenplum. I use postgresql driver connect it.

Comment: today, i modify the autoCommit to false. it's query fast. but i don't understand.

Comment: In both products it should not take more than a couple milliseconds. Usually. But: how big is the database? Did you analyze the table first? If you run the same query in psql, with \timing, does it need the same time? Local or remote connections?